# Definite integral equal to zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, roots

Can $A(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,s)\space dx $ have any zeros if $f(x,s)≠0$ for all complex $s$? $f(x,s)$ is a holomorphic function. Intuitively I would say $A(s)$ can't have any zeroes because the "area" between the function and the x-axis isn't zero since it never crosses zero, its bounds are not equal and $f(x,s)≠0$. The issue is that I can't really prove this and therefore I can't know for sure if I'm missing something. In short, what I'm wondering is the following: Does there exist an $s$ such that $A(s)=0$, and if not, could anyone provide a proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really well-formulated as one can easily do the following: note that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{-y^2}dy=0$ and the integral is absolutely convergent, while the function inside has only one finite zero at $y=0$.

Change variables $y=\ln x, y=\ln x -1$ and get absolute convergent integrals of functions $h,g$ on $[0,\infty)$, where $h(0)=h(1)=0, g(0)=g(e)=0, \int_{0}^{\infty}h(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx=0$ and $h,g$ have no other zeroes. Then shift variables for $h$ say, so for example we now take $h_1(x)=h(x-1), x \ge 1$,while we take say $h_1(x)=(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{3}), 0 \le x \le 1$ with integral zero on $[0,1]$ too (and we can smooth it more at $1$ if we want)

Now $h_1(x)+ig(x)$ has no zero when $x \ge 0$ and then if one takes $f(x,s)=e^s(h_1(x)+ig(x))$, $f(x,s)$ is holomorphic in $s$ and nonzero anywhere and $A(s)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand. How can you change $y$ to both ln $x$ and ln $x-1$?

Comment: there are two different changes of variables - you can rename the second to $u=\log x-1$ and think of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{-y^2}dy=0$ as two separate integrals, the other one being $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ue^{-u^2}du=0$ - the point is that you get two functions in $x$ which both have zero integral on $[0,\infty]$ and controllable zeroes - you can find tons of such examples, the one I chose is simple but you can pick others - I agree that the example is very contrived and not "realistic" but the point is that the question is way too vague as stated

Comment: Alright, now I understand. What do you mean by "too vague as stated" though? I'm new to this forum so I would love some feedback. Is it that the question is too general and that I have to come up with a more specific case than just $f(x,s)$?

Comment: the point is in what context did you see this question? why does it interest you? what do you want to use the answer for? - I think it is not a bad question per se, but it needs some focus, context, reason why it is interesting useful etc - the gamma function is defined like this and has no zeroes (though it is meromorphic), so I agree that in some contexts it may be true

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I'm only 16 and so my teachers aren't really educated for this. Now, the reason I'm asking is because I'm working with the Riemann Hypothesis for fun. I figured out the (non-trivial) zeros of the zeta function had a connection to the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-s}}{e^x-1}$d$x$. The function I'm integrating obviously doesn't have any zeroes. because it's essentially a fraction with 1 in the numerator, so I started wondering whether the integral could ever be equal to zero for some complex $s$.

Comment: the problem with that is that the integral as stated doesn't define RZ except in a domain where it doesn't have zeroes - to define it everywhere you need to make it a contour integral and that is complicated to analyze directly

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you very much for your time.